# How to perform additional jQuery code when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this HTML Markup:

```
<div class="wf__jqAPcontrol[1] wf__hide wf__optional" style="display: block;">
<label>Additional Info</label>
<fieldset class="wf__list wf__jqAPhtml" enabled="enabled">
<label for="specialDiscount\[1\]_529663" style="padding: 0 !important">
<input type="checkbox" value="-5.00" name="specialDiscount[1]" id="specialDiscount\[1\]_529663" class="wf__list jq__recomputeThisService" checked="checked"> Discount (5%)
</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I have this jQuery code:

```
if ( $('#specialDiscount\\[1\\]_529663').prop('checked') ) alert('checked');
else alert('unchecked');
```

I cannot get the jQuery to recognize the checkbox property. It always returns unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9ZNKb/)</kbd>

[Read This from jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>
> ```
> !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
> ```
>
> ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

`\` is also special meta-characters so to escape it you have to use `\`

```
var el = $('[id="specialDiscount\\\\[1\\\\]_529663"]');
//              ^            String               ^
if (el.prop('checked')) alert('checked');
else alert('unchecked');
```

for `\` you need  here `\\` as it is wrapped in quotes so it is string

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9ZNKb/1)</kbd>

```
var el = $('#specialDiscount\\\\\\[1\\\\\\]_529663');
```

for `\` you need `\\\\`

for `[` you need `\\[`

for `]` you need `\\]`

---

**Problem**

You selector is wrong so if condition always returns `false`

Comment: not sure what you mean @TusharGupta, can you help me out a bit ... what is wrong?